Integration testing with different testing components .net
I'm facing the problem where I need to create integration tests based on components it defines, for example if I want to test kafka with in memory database, I should be able to do it but without having taken care of teardowns and setups nor configurations, they should be done inside some base class. I had an idea to create classes which has ITestComponent interface, which has setup,teardown,onetimesetups,onetimeteardown. For example
public class KafkaTestComponent : ITestComponent
{
    private readonly KafkaTestContainer _container;
    private readonly KafkaTestTopicsManager _topicsManager;
    private readonly KafkaTestClient _client;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="KafkaTestComponent"/> class
    /// </summary>
    public KafkaTestComponent()
    {
        _container = new KafkaTestContainer();
        _topicsManager = new KafkaTestTopicsManager(_container.BootStrapServer);
        _client = new KafkaTestClient(_container.BootStrapServer);
    }

I've also builder pattern so I would be able to define some component that I need for testing and the passed it to the base class which would take care of setups,teardowns and configurations.
public class SomeTestClass : BackgroundServiceTestBase
{
    private KafkaTestComponent _kafka;
    // InMemoryDatabase is custom defined with it's in memory configurations and etc.
    private InMemoryDatabase<SomeContext> _database;

    /// <inheritdoc/>
    protected override TestingComponentsBuilder ConfigureTestingComponents(TestingComponentsBuilder testingComponentsBuilder)
    {
        _kafka = new KafkaTestComponent();
        _database = new InMemoryDatabase<SomeContext>();

        return testingComponentsBuilder
            .With(_kafka)
            .With(_database);
    }


public abstract class BackgroundServiceTestBase
{
    // There are one time setups and teardowns as well
    [SetUp]
    public async Task BackgroundServiceTestBaseSetUp()
    {
        _hostBuilder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder();
        ConfigureHostBuilder(_hostBuilder);
        _hostBuilder.ConfigureServices(_testingComponents.ConfigureServices);
        _host = _hostBuilder.Build();

        await _testingComponents.SetUpAsync();
    }
}


Problem that I've got is that I'm getting race condition, because I'm not re-creating the database, not re-creating kafka component for example with new keyword and so these things causes problems between tests. Any idea how can I done this?
I've tried removing abstract teardowns and setups (for example _testingComponents.Setup()) and have real one like _database = new InMemoryDatabase() inside base class and it worked, because I was re-creating them every time, same goes for kafka as well.
